# TIdTcpServer Stop Accept New Connections After Some Time

Tags: delphi, indy10

i already tried use TIdTcpServer many times, and i always have the same issue.
after some time working (receiving connections) he stop receive new connections and need restart him for back work.

the code who i use now it's very simply, but the problem still happening. and i don't know what do more, i'm almost purchasing a connection framework for see if solve the problem.

```
procedure TForm1.ClientStateUpdated(Client: TClient; Texto: String);
var
  PeerIP, HostName: string;
begin
  PeerIP    := Client.IP;
  HostName  := Client.HWID;

  TThread.Queue(nil,
  procedure
  begin
    if ((PeerIP <> '') and (HostName <> '')) then Memo2.Lines.Add(Format(Texto, [TimeToStr(Now), PeerIP, HostName]));
  end);
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Conexao : TClient;
  Retorno : TArray<String>;
  Query   : TFDQuery;
  Libera  : Boolean;
  IPEX    : Boolean;
begin
  Libera  := True;
  IPEX    := True;
  Conexao := TClient(AContext);
  Retorno := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn(LF, 5000).Split(['#']);

  if Length(Retorno) = 0 then
  begin
    AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
    Exit;
  end;

  if Retorno[0] = 'cmdPing' then Retorno[1] := Retorno[2];

  Conexao.IP          := AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;
  Conexao.HWID        := Retorno[1];
  Conexao.Connected   := Now;
  Conexao.Ping        := Ticks;

  ClientStateUpdated(Conexao, "%s %s %s");
  Conexao.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('cmdContinue');
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  ClientStateUpdated(TClient(AContext), RetornaTraducao(32));
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Conexao       : TClient;
  Retorno       : TArray<String>;
begin
  Conexao := TClient(AContext);
  Retorno := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn.Split(['#']);
end;
```

Others declarations:

```
type
  TClient = class(TIdServerContext)
    private
      FCriticalSection  : TCriticalSection;
    public
      IP          : String;
      HWID        : String;

      Connected   : TDateTime;
      Ping        : Cardinal;   
      Queue       : TIdThreadSafeStringList;

      constructor Create(AConnection: TIdTCPConnection; AYarn: TIdYarn; AList: TIdContextThreadList = nil); override;
      destructor  Destroy; override;
      procedure   Lock;
      procedure   Unlock;
  end;

constructor TClient.Create(AConnection: TIdTCPConnection; AYarn: TIdYarn; AList: TIdContextThreadList = nil);
begin
  inherited Create(AConnection, AYarn, AList);

  FCriticalSection  := TCriticalSection.Create;
  Queue             := TIdThreadSafeStringList.Create;
end;

destructor TClient.Destroy;
begin
  Queue.Free;
  FreeAndNil(FCriticalSection);

  inherited;
end;

procedure TClient.Lock;
begin
  FCriticalSection.Enter;
end;

procedure TClient.Unlock;
begin
  FCriticalSection.Leave;
end;
```

The strange thing is, if i create an application who connect/disconnect and run it for MANY hours application works fine, but when i release it for public the problem come.

i don't use IdSchedulerOfThreadDefault1 / IdSchedulerOfThreadPool1

Comment: This is hardly a [mcve], so it is hard to diagnose what the problem is exactly. What does `RetornaTraducao()` do? How are `TClient.(Un)Lock()` being used? I don't see how any of this code can affect the server's ability to accept connections, that happens on a separate thread than the one each `TClient` runs in.

Comment: This is all the code from server, RetornaTraducao just get the string like "%s %s %s" nothing more, about Lock/Unlock i don't use. how i should use it and where?
i've updated the topic and removed the RetornaTraducao and replaced for "%s %s %s" who is what he gets

Comment: I created an application who connect/disconnect here and are testing now aroung 80k of connect/disconnect and working good, but for some reason when i release it for public this problem happens

Comment: "*when i release it for public this problem happens*" - that tells us absolutely nothing useful. I don't see anything blatantly obvious in the code you have shown so far that can cause this issue. So it has to be in code you have not shown yet. You are just going to have to debug your code on a system that is failing.

Comment: How should i use (Un)Lock() ? because i don't use it, the code is only that who i writed here, nothing more.

Comment: That are right? it's how i should use WriteLn on OnConnect event?

Conexao.Lock;
try
    Conexao.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('cmdContinue');
  finally
    Conexao.Unlock;
  end;

Comment: As say here "Use TCriticalSection to safeguard operations that may be disrupted if another thread executes certain sections of code before the operation is completed. Critical sections work like gates that allow only a single thread to enter at a time. Because they block the execution of other threads, overusing critical sections can seriously interfere with performance. " so i don't need use it at OnConnect event.

Comment: I don't know why your code has a `TCriticalSection` at all.  `TIdThreadSafeStringList` has its own internal one. The only reason I could see for having `(Un)Lock()` methods in `TClient` is if you plan on accessing the `IOHandler` across multiple threads, which I don't recommend doing. But since you haven't shown all of your code, I cant comment on whether the `TCriticalSection` is actually being used for something meaningful, or if it can safely be removed.

Comment: TIdTcpServer hangs if app was compiled as 64 bits? because the same app who generate some problems compiled as 64 on 32 don't happen. and you know why ApplicationEvents1 can't handle all exceptions, i use him with ApplicationEvents1Exception and show some memory access error at window on some cases. can this handle cause some problem at IdTcpServer? at handle their errors?